# How to write an intinerary email that Gmail will recognize

Tags: gmail, google-now, inbox-by-gmail

I want to email myself some flight details. How can I write the email so that Gmail will recognize the flights and make an auto event? Or, how do I make Inbox recognize it as a travel category email?

I understand that it might not be possible. Even when I receive itineraries straight from the airline, it normally doesn't recognize them anyway! Irritating that this feature is so half-baked.

Comment: I just realised, you can set any email as Travel within the Inbox app

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/flight-reservation

Comment: @MatthewRead Useful for some, but I don't know how to do send an html email

Comment: Should I ask this on Superuser instead?

Comment: I think this might be most suited to [WebApps.SE] since it's Gmail's backend that is handling this, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: But the notifications would come in Google Now, which only happens on Android, right?

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past (you're not alone in this want!) is take other emails that I've gotten from other flights and replaced all the information with my new flight that I wish to track. Make sure you hit the most important parts

- Itinerary number
- Confirmation code
- Flight numbers
- Incoming/outgoing airports
- All flight times

Once I filled in all my new information, I just forwarded myself that email and Gmail picked it up and even pushed the info into Google Now!

Pretty handy.